# How to inject JS into an application using Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: javascript, chromium, chromium-embedded, browser-extension

I am attempting to inject a piece of JavaScript into a Mac application using Chromium Embedded Framework internally. I have tried using the command line options mentioned in the CEF documentation (load-extension), but I have not much success at getting any JavaScript running.

Is `--load-extension` supposed to load any browser extension when used with a CEF build? Or are there other things that need to be present for this to work? Are there limitations to what can be loaded here? I have yet to find a good example of using --load-extension in the wild.

Comment: CEF only supports a small subset of the Chrome extension API, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions for details. Far as I know --load-extension is part of cefclient and not part of the framework itself. From my experience CEF will only load an extracted extension. You'll need to unzip the crx file manually

Comment: See also https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration.md

Comment: If you have further questions I'd ask them on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php

Comment: Thank you. It seems like any application built with CEF will have to programmatically expose the extension loading capabilities. So unless I can convince the developers of that application to allow extensions, this will be "impossible" as it stands.